# python code to wait for push button to be pushed

Tags: python, arduino

I am using python to control an arduino.I want the python code to wait for the button to be pressed, and then move onto the next line.In the current code I have, the code sleeps for x seconds and checks if button has been pushed,if button is not pushed, it skips it.
This is my current code:

```
    if bool(push_button2.read()):
        print('Please press any button when done')
        sleep(2)
        if bool(push_button1.read()) or bool(push_button2.read()):
```

The problem with this is if `push_button1 or push_button2` is not pressed, it will move onto the next code.So is there a way to make python wait for an input via the push button?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `while` for this:

```
while(!push_button2.read())
    pass
```

Or you can even add s small `sleep()` here:

```
while(!push_button2.read())
    sleep(0.01)
```

And finally, you can write your own functions:

```
# wait for one button
def wait_for_button(button):
    while(!button.read())
        pass

# wait for any button from a set
# usage: wait_for_any_button(button1, button2)
def wait_for_any_button(*args):
    while !any(map(lambda b: b.read(), args)):
        pass

# if you need a button index
def wait_for_any_button_i(*args):
    while True:
        for i, button in enumerate(args):
            if button.read():
                return i
```

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/15844/pause-code-untill-a-button-is-pressed

Comment: Is it possible to make it such that ie:
`wait_for_button(push_button1)
    print('1')
wait_for_button(push_button2)
    print('2')`
This is such that if button 1 is pressed, it prints'1'.If button 2 is pressed, it prints'2'.The issue I have with this function is that,referring to the code above,if button 2 is pressed before button 1, nothing is printed.In summary, the function is such that button 1 must be pressed before button 2, such that it executes.Is there a way that doesnt have this kind of flow?But really props to you man, great code!

Comment: of course, that is why I added `wait_for_any_button_i` function. It can tell you an index of pressed button. So that you can write: 
```pressed = wait_for_any_button_i(button0, button1);
if pressed == 0: print('Button 0 pressed!')
else  print('Button 1 pressed!')```

Comment: I also wanted to add this `if int(round(time.time())) - now == 5:
        buzz_pin.write(1)
        sleep(5)
        buzz_pin.write(0)
        break`
so the logic behind this is that if a button is not pressed in 5 sec, the buzzer sounds,is this possible?